# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException error and asking to upgrade MySQL client

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, tomcat, jdbc

I have deployed my application on tomcat server.

In My Application, I have written code for rest web service api implementation where I am trying to establish connection to mySQL database.

Code is as below :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.
getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pharmacy", "pharm", "@Pharm123");
```

I am using mySQL connector verion 8.0.11.

when I debugging I got to know that it was throwing exception like below

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException Client does 
not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading 
MySQL client
```

and I have also tried the below steps in mySQL database

```
use pharmacy;
CREATE USER 'pharm'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '@Pharm123';
GRANT ALL ON pharmacy.* TO 'pharm'@'localhost';
```

Can u please guide me how to proceed further?

Comment: Check that the version 8.0.11 of MySQL Connector/J is really loaded.

Comment: Yes i have added it under maven dependicies for this particular procect

Comment: The error means you are using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45 or earlier. Upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46 or 8.0.11. If you think you are using 8.0.11, make sure there isn't an older version of the driver somewhere (eg in the tomcat `lib` folder).

Comment: @Mark , nowhere under the lib folder older version of MySQL Connector Exists , it has of latest version only i.e 8.0.11

Comment: In that case, please post the full stacktrace